# I need Help, How to run Timer there?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, collision, game-development

I created a bonus for the game, which increase the main player’s size when you pick him. I wrote a script, but timer doesn't work when the player and bonus are collide, how to fix it?

When you start coroutine in `Start()` method, the timer work correctly, but I want to start timer after collision.

Bonus: player pick him and start timer for 10 sec. In this period, player's size change for 10 sec, then return to the original size.

```
public GameObject effect;
public GameObject Player;
bool bol = false; 
float Timeremaining = 3f;
float CurrentTime;

public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube")
    {
        bol = true;
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        Instantiate(effect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        RipplePostProcessor.bloom++;
        Debug.Log(bol);
        StartTimeEvent();
    }
}
public void StartTimeEvent()
{
    if (bol == true)
        StartCoroutine(StartCountDown());
    else
        StopCoroutine("StartCountDown");   
}

public IEnumerator StartCountDown()
{
    CurrentTime = Timeremaining;
    while (CurrentTime > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("CountDown :" + CurrentTime);
        Player.transform.localScale = new Vector3(5, 5, 5);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        CurrentTime--;
        if (CurrentTime < 1)
        {
            bol = false;
            Player.transform.localScale = new Vector3(3, 3, 1);
            Debug.Log(bol);
        }
    }
}
```